# How to attach gdb to a subprocess started from Python script?

Tags: python, gdb

I have the following Python 3 script

`foobar.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import subprocess
import sys

p = subprocess.Popen(["./foobar"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False)
sys.stdin.read(1)
p.stdin.write("f".encode())
p.stdin.flush()
sys.stdin.read(1)
```

which starts the program `foobar` compiled from the following file `foobar.c` with `-g` option:

`foobar.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char c;

    if (EOF == scanf("%c", &c)) {
        perror(NULL);
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("received char %c\n", c);
    return(0);
}
```

I start the script, it waits for me to enter a character, I hit `Enter`, and I get `f`:

```
>./foobar.py

received char f
```

OK, what I would like, is to inspect `foobar` with the debugger `gdb`.  That is what `sys.stdin.read(1)` is for:  I hoped to start

```
>./foobar.py
```

and then, in another terminal, find out the process id of `foobar`, and run

`>gdb attach`pid`-ex='b foobar.c:12'`

then I was hoping to hit `Enter` in the first terminal as before, and then the C program would eat the input and stop at the line 12, which is `printf`, as requested.

But it does not work this way - I hit `Enter` and nothing happens, the program `foobar` does not budge, it still waits at `scanf`.

How to do it so that I can stop at `printf` ?

Comment: you have to send `p.stdin.write("f\n".encode())`. Alternately `p.stdin.close()`. That should work.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre well, that's cheating...  I can't do that.  I have the programs `foobar.py` and `foobar.c` as given, and they work as shown above.  So, they should also work under the debugger - I can insert `sys.stdin.read(1)` to "stop" so I can attach the debugger, but that's all I can do.  I can't go around and change other things.  That is the whole point of using the debugger, rather than inserting "print" statements, that you don't change your code.  The code above is just an SSCCE, you understand?  The "real" code is far bigger.

Comment: not that's not: `scanf` expects a char + linefeed. So it's not possible to make those both work with the .py and .c code. you can challenge anyone here to make that work, not possible, because of the way `scanf` processes input.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre what do you mean - I did get them to work, just like I shown above. It's not about challenging or arguing, it's about checking one's question prior to posting.

Comment: the problem is that `gdb` prevents the stream to be closed. by starting without gdb, the input stream is closed & flushed and the C program recieves f+EOF. With the debugger, it doesn't receive EOF or linefeed.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I see your point.  I updated the question based on your comment - I added the `flush` and another `read` to prevent closing of the script.  The problem is still happening, even after I updated according to your comment.  Please take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to do it so that I can stop at printf ?
>    gdb attach `pid` -ex='b foobar.c:12'

It's not clear what the *exact* meaning of `gdb attach pid -ex ...` is.

Did you forget to continue the inferior process (which is stopped by GDB attaching to it)?

This worked perfectly fine for me:

```
$ gdb -q -ex "attach $(pidof foobar)" -ex 'break foobar.c:12' -ex continue
Attaching to process 88748
Reading symbols from /tmp/stdin/foobar...done.
0x00007f9b78811330 in __read_nocancel () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:81
81  ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S: No such file or directory.
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400664: file foobar.c, line 12.
Continuing.
```

... GDB just sits here (as expected). After I hit `Enter` in the `foobar.py` window:

```
Breakpoint 1, main () at foobar.c:12
12      printf("received char %c\n", c);
```

Comment: "did you forget to continue" - well I assumed, that since the process was already running, it does not get "stopped", is that right, does it get stopped by `gdb` attaching while it is running?

Comment: When you see the `(gdb)` prompt, the inferior process *is stopped* (at least in default `all-stop` mode). And yes, `gdb -ex "attach ..."` will immediately stop the attached-to process.

Comment: thank you ! that was it, I did not realize, I needed `-ex continue` . Previously, I did use `continue` and the whole thing fell through, without stopping at all, I must have done something else wrong.  Now, I do it and "somehow" it works.